# Python login check auths any correct letter

Tags: python

The issue I keep having is that after I register a username/password, then try to login if I get any letters or numbers of the login/password correct it accepts it, for example if my username is Fof and my Password is tog and I enter the username as just f or o it will accept it.

Here's the code written in Python idle 3.7:

```
if  Game == "1":
    username = input("Please enter your username: ")
    if username in open("Names.txt").read(): #fix
            print ("Welcome " + username)
            password = input("Please enter your password: ")
            if password in open("Passwords.txt").read():
                    print ("success!")
    else:
                    print("Username incorrect!")
```

Comment: Check for a boundary word. using regex

Comment: Can you share content of `Names.txt` and `Passwords.txt`

Comment: "f" in "Fof" evaluates as True

Comment: @Alderven sure, here is my **`Passwords.txt`**

Comment: I dont understand completely. From what I see, if you search for something **IN** something else, a simple character suffices.
So you should not search for password IN something, but password must equal exactly something, right?

Comment: According to that logic one user can login with password of other user

Answer (score 0):

An explanation of what you need:

You need to look for the **exact** match of the word in the file, not just `in` because that would always return `True` and hence it would bypass:

An example:

NamesList:

```
Fof
Abc
Def
```

and then:

```
import re

text = input("enter Name to be searched:")    
NamesFile = open("NamesList.txt", "r") 

for line in NamesFile:
    if re.search(r"\b" + text +  r"\b", line):
        print(line)
    else:
        print("Name not found")
        break
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
enter Name to be searched:Fof
Fof
```

**In another case**:

```
enter Name to be searched:f
Name not found
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store logins and passwords the way you do, then one user can use password of another user and vice versa. It's better to store login-password pair together:

File `credentials.json`:

```
{"Fof": "tog"}
```

Code:

```
import json

with open('credentials.json') as f:
    credentials = json.load(f)

username = input('Please enter your username: ')
if credentials.get(username):
        print('Welcome {}'.format(username))
        password = input('Please enter your password: ')
        if credentials[username] == password:
                print('success!')
else:
        print('Username incorrect!')
```

Let's try to hack:

```
Please enter your username: f
Username incorrect!
```

Successful login:

```
Please enter your username: Fof
Welcome Fof
Please enter your password: tog
success!
```